# PopUp at the end of button's operations

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my aspx page I have a button that save several values in the database.

I need to insert a popuup at the end of the operation.

At the moment the code is:

```
protected void btnSendRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myDbAccess = new DBAccess();
    Event newEvent = (Event)Session["NewEvent"];

    myDbAccess.SaveEvent(newEvent);

    // Insert here a PopUp like "Successfully saved!"

}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Luigi

Answer (score 1):

you should use `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` to open the popup.

**Example**

```
protected void btnSendRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myDbAccess = new DBAccess();
    Event newEvent = (Event)Session["NewEvent"];

    myDbAccess.SaveEvent(newEvent);

    // Insert here a PopUp like "Successfully saved!"
    var popupCode = @"<script>alert ('Javascript block of code executed')</script>";
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"myKey",popupCode);

}
```

you could also remove the  block from your string by using an overload like the following

```
protected void btnSendRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myDbAccess = new DBAccess();
    Event newEvent = (Event)Session["NewEvent"];

    myDbAccess.SaveEvent(newEvent);

    // Insert here a PopUp like "Successfully saved!"
    var popupCode = @"alert ('Javascript block of code executed');";
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"myKey",popupCode,true);

}
```

note the `TRUE` value at the end of the `RegisterClientScriptBlock` method.

try the above code and let me know what happened.

Comment: It gives me this error:

Errore: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by the following:

```
protected void btnSendRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myDbAccess = new DBAccess();
    Event newEvent = (Event)Session["NewEvent"];

    myDbAccess.SaveEvent(newEvent);

    // Insert here a PopUp like "Successfully saved!"

   string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('successfully saved');</script>";
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script);
}
```

I hope this helps. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

you  can use like this :

```
   string Scr=@"<script language='javascript'></script>";
   ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
   cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript",Scr, false);
   cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "My alert", "alert('" Saved Successfully"');", true);
```

Note the first `RegisterStartupScript` has `False` for last parameter and next has `True`

For More Help :- [RegisterClientScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx)

Comment: try this edited code and let me know if any problem you face.

Comment: I've tried in this way: 



string Scr=@"<script language='javascript'></script>"; 
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript; 
cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript",Scr, false); 
cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "My alert", "alert('Saved Successfully');", true);


but nothing happens. 


Luigi

Answer (score 0):

Jquery model dialog is best.You can easily integrate this with asp.net.

- [jquery method](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-use-jquery-dialog-in-aspnet.html)
- You could use the [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx) method from the code
  behind:

---

```
public void SomeButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string script = "$('#someid').dialog('open');";
       ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "popup", script, true);
   }
```

---

- [jquery plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) or [Colorbox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)
- [ModalPopupExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)